# Pressure in elevator and velocity

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, velocity

Basically from this graph I'm trying to determine how far the elevator traveled and how fast it was moving during its trip down.  The accepted density of air during this experiment was $1.17\cfrac{\text{kg}}{m^3}$. I already tried to plug this into the formulas but my answer according to my teacher was way off so I was hoping if someone could explain this to me and how I can do it. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What I'm putting here would normally go in the comments, but I have too little reputation, so I have no choice.

You seem inconsistent with your questions. Your first question involving "how far the elevator traveled and how fast it was moving during its trip down" is a simple question. "How far the elevator traveled" can be solved using an integral of the position function, with bounds set from $t = 0$ and $t = n$, where $t$ is the variable for time and $n$ is the total amount of time taken. "How fast it was moving during its trip down" is vague, but if you're looking for *instantaneous* speed, you would take the derivative of the position function; if you're looking for *average* speed, simply find the slope of the function from the first to the last point.

However, your second question involves a different concept. You can solve for the pressure of the ideal gas using the formula $P=pRT$, where $p$ is the density (which you have), $R$ is a constant, and $T$ is the temperature (not given). You have $P$ as well, which is given by your graph.

Comment: Should be a $v$ in the bottom eqn?

Comment: That is in the equation that relates pressure with *volume*, not pressure with *density*

Comment: Here's more info: https://byjus.com/physics/relation-between-pressure-and-density/#:~:text=The%20pressure%20and%20density%20relationship%20for%20ideal%20gases,density%20increases.%20When%20the%20pressure%20decreases%2C%20density%20decreases.

Comment: Oh i missed “p is density”. You can write \rho  . Just fyi. But my mistake

Answer (score 0):

The pressure gives you volume. Assume constant T and constant amount of gas trapped under it. From PV=nRT we have only two things changing.

$V \propto \frac{1}{P}$ , $V=\frac{k}{P}$, where $k$ is a constant.

The volume is the cross-sectional area, times the height. The cross-sectional area doesn’t change, so what do you know about height and volume? (Hint: do the proportional thing again for H and V, and then get some proportionality between H and P.) Velocity of course is dH/dt, and hopefully by now you have some relation between height H, and P.

Velocity aside, since the amount of gas trapped is the same, then when you get back to a previous pressure value, then you have returned to a corresponding volume value (and what do we know about V and H?).

That’s more than enough of a hint. We can’t do it for you. Good luck